# Calculating Date difference and matching it with array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way in JavaScript that I can check if date is between 2 dates?

I have an array like

```
var unavailableDates = ["5-7-2011","6-7-2011","7-7-2011","15-7-2011","16-7-2011","17-7-2011" ];
```

and now I have 2 dates like `1-7-2011` and `10-7-2011`. I want to see if any value from `unavailableDates` falls between these date. If it falls it should return alert.

Can someone help me on this? I am in process of learning more about JavaScript and jQuery. I am not able to code it the way I understood the problem.

Comment: i am using the jquery ui plugin and is struck with my own ideas of customizing it so as a custom complete calender is available to one all to use
here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/pTaUZ/
using the solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have the solution

```
var unavailableDates = ["5-7-2011","6-7-2011","7-7-2011","15-7-2011","16-7-2011","17-7-2011" ];
function str2date(sdate){ //This function gets a string and return a Date object
   var parts = sdate.split("-");
   return new Date(parts[2], parseInt(parts[1], 10)-1, parts[0]);
}
var stamp1 = str2date("1-7-2011").getTime(); //First date. getTime() converts it to an integer
var stamp2 = str2date("10-7-2011").getTime(); //Second date
for(var i=0; i<unavailableDates.length; i++){
   var curStamp = str2date(unavailableDates[i]).getTime();
   if(curStamp >= stamp1 && curStamp <= stamp2) //Check if it falls in range
       alert(unavailableDates[i] + " falls in range");
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: THanks for quick solution when i try to add above in my custom problem i get all date alerted
here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/pTaUZ/
wanna look? if pleased to help

Comment: I've corrected a bug in my code (regarding month), check the fourth line please. However, you were calculating wrong the mindate in your code, you should do it like maxdate, so have: `var theMinDate = new Date(Date.parse($("#datepicker_1").datepicker('getDate')));        
 var mindate = $.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', theMinDate);`  
I've updated your fiddle.

Comment: thanks i will look into it and learn more about it, thanks for insights, +1 and answer accepted , can you consider voting for my question

Comment: You're welcome. I've voted, and you gained a friend. edgarinvillegas at hotmail dot com.

Answer (score 0):

Date object in JavaScript allows compare operation, you only required to have proper Date objects. Create Date objects from your bounds and array members and compare them in a loop.

More information about Date object could be found there: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp